# Debugging Cloud Build database connection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-build

My cloud build CI pipe is failing with very little debug information, but several factors point to a failing database connection. This is the last part of the build log:

```
...
Step #3 - "tests": webpack compiled successfully
Step #3 - "tests": [ info ]  running tests...
Step #3 - "tests": 
Step #3 - "tests":    connect ENOENT /cloudsql/w121-cms:europe-west1:w121/.s.PGSQL.5432
Step #3 - "tests":   
Step #3 - "tests": 
Finished Step #3 - "tests"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 3 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

This is my build script:

```yaml
steps:
  - id: install
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    args: ['install']

  - id: lint
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    args: ['run', 'lint']

  - id: proxy-install
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    entrypoint: sh
    args:
      - -c
      - 'wget -O /workspace/cloud_sql_proxy https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.386 &&  chmod +x /workspace/cloud_sql_proxy'

  - id: tests
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    timeout: 100s
    entrypoint: sh
    args:
      - -c
      - '(/workspace/cloud_sql_proxy $PROJECT_ID:europe-west1:w121 & sleep 2) && npm run ci:test'
    env:
      - 'NODE_ENV=test'
      - 'DB_CONNECTION=pg'
      - 'PG_HOST=/cloudsql/$PROJECT_ID:europe-west1:w121'
      - 'PG_PORT=5432'
      - 'PG_USER=postgres'
      - 'PG_DB_NAME=testing'
      - others ...
    secretEnv: ['PG_PASSWORD', 'APP_KEY']

availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
    - env: 'PG_PASSWORD'
      versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/PG_PASSWORD/versions/1
    - env: 'APP_KEY'
      versionName: projects/$PROJECT_ID/secrets/APP_KEY/versions/1
```

What I have checked:

### Connection parameters

All of `DB_CONNECTION`, `PG_HOST`, `PG_PORT` and `PG_USER` are the same as in another working build script. From the log output we can see that the $PROJECT_ID in the host value resolves correctly. There definitely is a database called `testing` in that postgres instance.

### Service worker permissions

Running this query:

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy $PROJECTNUM
```

I get this confirmation that the build account can access secrets and the Cloud SQL service:

```
bindings:
- members:
  - serviceAccount:610825299606@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/cloudbuild.builds.builder
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service-610825299606@gcp-sa-cloudbuild.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/cloudbuild.serviceAgent
- members:
  - serviceAccount:610825299606@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/cloudsql.client
- members:
  - serviceAccount:610825299606-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
  - serviceAccount:610825299606@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor
```

### Network access

In my cd script I successfully run migrations on the same database instance using gcr.io/google-appengine/exec-wrapper and similar connection variables. Because I don't want to to add a build artifact with every pull request, I am here not building, pushing and running inside a container, but trying to connect via a proxy tunnel.

Can anyone spot a problem or have suggestions on how to debug this futher?

Thanks!

Comment: I've only had limited cloud_sql_proxy use, but don't you have to specify `-instances=PROJ_ID:REGION:CLOUDSQL_INSTANCE_NAME=tcp:DB_PORT` ?

Comment: @GlenYu good pointer! I tried `cloud_sql_proxy -instances=$PROJECT_ID:europe-west1:w121=tcp:5432` but it still fails with same error message

Comment: Honestly I don't really see any issues with your setup per se.  Only thing I can suggest is perhaps splitting your && into something more like:

```
args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    /workspace/cloud_sql_proxy $PROJECT_ID:europe-west1:w121 & sleep 2;
    npm run ci:test
```

instead just in case the ( ) causes any problems

EDIT: ugh, formatting :(  , but see this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-build-samples/blob/a66407bc412a2726781f30063923a49bb6789064/sql-proxy/cloudbuild.yaml#L52) for an example of what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So! Finally got the CI pipe working. The trip-up was with the PG_HOST value. When I run the cloud proxy locally it reports:

> Listening on /path/to/project/w121-cms:europe-west1:w121/.s.PGSQL.5432 for w121-cms:europe-west1:w121

But running it in the pipe it was:

> Listening on 127.0.0.1:5432 for w121-cms:europe-west1:w121

The config step that worked was then:

```yaml
  - id: proxy-install
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    entrypoint: sh
    args:
      - -c
      - |
        wget -O /workspace/cloud_sql_proxy https://dl.google.com/cloudsql/cloud_sql_proxy.linux.386
        chmod +x /workspace/cloud_sql_proxy

  - id: tests
    name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    timeout: 100s
    entrypoint: sh
    args:
      - -c
      - |
        /workspace/cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/workspace -instances=w121-cms:europe-west1:w121=tcp:5432 & sleep 2
        npm run ci:test
    env:
      - 'NODE_ENV=test'
      - 'DB_CONNECTION=pg'
      - 'PG_HOST=127.0.0.1'
      - 'PG_PORT=5432'
      - 'PG_USER=postgres'
      - 'PG_DB_NAME=testing'
    secretEnv: ['PG_PASSWORD', 'APP_KEY']
```